# How do I migrate comments?

Tags: 7, migrations, comments

I am trying out the Migrate module, to move my site from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, but I dont see comments being moved; just the content is migrated.

How do I migrate comments too?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.drupal.org/node/1819714 ?

Comment: ...and http://cgit.drupalcode.org/migrate/tree/plugins/destinations/comment.inc

Comment: comments were migrated....but I am missing the images.....dunno how to fix that problem.....

Comment: it works for categories and content...but not for images...that were added just by using file upload button